# Burn CD/DVD from C++ program

Tags: c++

I need to burn CD/DVD disks from my C++ program. Can you recommend me a method?

Edit: The platform is Windows.

Comment: A platform would really help here with answering this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12133670/1566316

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, I have previously used the IMAPI2 interface very successfully.  [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/IMAPI2.aspx) site gives a really good set of sample code for this.  You may need to extensively modify the code for your implementation, but it works, and works well.

One thing about the IMAPI2 interface; it's what you pretty much need to use if you're going to be writing to DVDs, as previous iterations of the IMAPI interface had inconsistent handling of writing to DVDs.

Comment: Microsoft has a patch or hotfix or whatever they call them for running IMAPI2 on XP.  I've used it, and it works fine.

Comment: I'll use IMAPI2. Thank you for advice.

Comment: You're welcome; it worked well for us; hope you have similar success.

Answer (score 3):

Why not call a cdrecord or growisofs or whatever console utility?

That's easy, doesn't requires anything, just drag that small executable with you.
They are also known to work just fine.

Comment: Who said anything about UNIX/Linux?

Comment: Windows port of cdrecord does exists. I guess I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

On windows you can use the "Image Mastering API".

Check it out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366450(VS.85).aspx)