# What are some common C libraries in Linux to use a CD burning device?

Tags: c, libraries, iso, cd-burning

I am interested in creating software that uses a CD burning device. I will be writing this code in C under Linux and compiling using GCC.

Answer (score 6):

[libburn](http://libburnia-project.org) as the name suggests ;) (and other friend-libraries from the same site). It's used in [brasero](http://projects.gnome.org/brasero/) (GNOME), [xfburn](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/applications/xfburn) (xfce) and [cdw](http://cdw.sourceforge.net).

And well, *that's it*. Really, I'm not aware of any more libraries.

In fact, it *was* more common to wrap command-line `cdrecord` (from [cdrtools](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/cdrecord.html) or [cdrkit](http://cdrkit.org)) but they never provided a shared library; it was just an old unix practice on running external executables (and then parsing their output, *ugly*). AFAIK it's still used in [k3b](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/cdrecord.html) and a few minor tools but the general trend is migration towards libburn.